# What does "なくす" mean in this phrase?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, phrases, japanese-to-english

カメラで人を見つけて踏切の事故をなくす

I don't know a meaning of "Nakusu" in this phrase. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What do you think the rest of the sentence means? What might you want to do about such things?

Comment: I looked up one of the meanings of "Nakusu" and it's like "to lose", but I don't know how it would fit in this sentence. A sentence is title of news from "NHK". Sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> カメラで人を見つけて踏切の事故をなくす。

So the sentence is about accidents at "railway crossings" (踏切の事故). And we are doing something to them "by finding people using a camera" (カメラで人を見つけて). What might you be able to do about accidents using a camera? One logical answer is to "get rid" of them / "eliminate" them etc. Sounds a bit like "lose" don't you think? So a translation could be

> We will eliminate accidents at level crossings by using a camera that finds/detects people.